# Getting value from text input using document.getElementByID not working

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a simple project with javascript and it requires me to get a value out of an HTML text input with javascript. In the following code I've found that nothing after line 6 works and I have no idea why. This has been driving me crazy for like two hours and I'm kind of at my wits end. Please help!

```
function letsPlayAGame() {
  var answer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);

  var guess = document.getElementByID("theinput").value;

  if (Number.isInteger(guess) == false) {
    document.getElementByID("label").innerHTML =
      "Please enter a number between 1 and 100!";
  } else if (guess < 1 || guess > 100) {
    document.getElementByID("label").innerHTML =
      "Please enter a number between 1 and 100!";
  } else {
    alert("not this part");
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide relevant HTML and clarify which is line 6?

Comment: Also note that JavaScript is case sensitive, `getElementById` instead of `getElementByID`

Comment: Yep, that was the problem! Going to go and scream a bit now, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
document.getElementById
```

instead of

```
document.getElementByID
```

as Javascript is case sensitive.